# optimization of a linear system of inequalites

Tags: matlab, math, inequalities

We are given four points, assumed to be ordered:

```
A = sort(randn(1,4))
```

I want to find the maximum possible number `x` in the interval `0<x<1` such that

```
A(1)<x<A(2) or A(3)<x<A(4)
```

Some examples:

```
A = [-1.4924    0.3004    1.6630     2.1204], x = 0.3004
A = [-0.4754    0.1353    0.6552     1.3873]; x = 1.0000
A = [-1.0213   -0.4521   -0.0905     0.1000]; x = 0.1000
A = [-1.8258   -0.5790   -0.4568    -0.1950]; x = 0.0000
A = [ 1.5000    2.0000    2.5000     3.0000]; x = 1.0000
```

Can you suggest a compact code to do this job, without having to list all the possible scenarios using `if` statements?

Comment: Can you explain the second row? Where does the 1 come from?

Comment: the maximum value of 0<x<1 in the interval (0.6552; 1.3873) is x=1, and 1>0.1353, so the answer is x=1

Comment: x = 0 in row 4 violates the logical condition.

Comment: Simplex method is the way to do it.  Don't guess.

Comment: What's wrong with writing a few `if` statements? There aren't that many different cases. Is this a simplification of a more general problem which you wish to solve?

Comment: I'm not really sure, but this does not seem to be a convex problem, so any `fminsearch` or similar will have problems. I'd go with a logic-search, i.e. always take `min([1 max([0 A(4)]])` except when `A(3)>1`, then `max([0 A(2)])`, something like that

Comment: If `A = [1.5 2 2.5 3]`, what would be the value of `x` in this case?

Comment: If `all(A>1)`, then the answer is `x=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having tried to do this with no if statements, I found that the readability of the code was greatly diminished. Note that there is only a single if statement in the code below while several other if statements could be substituted for the logical comparisons.

All of your tests pass and the code remains very concise (9 lines without the comments and loop over all of the tests).

```
A = [[-1.4924    0.3004    1.6630     2.1204];
     [-0.4754    0.1353    0.6552     1.3873];
     [-1.0213   -0.4521   -0.0905     0.1000];
     [-1.8258   -0.5790   -0.4568    -0.1950];
     [ 1.5000    2.0000    2.5000     3.0000]];

for i = 1:size(A,1)
    % Reshape A so that each set of 2 entries are compared
    Atmp = reshape(A(i,:),2,2);

    % Find any valid entries
    Valid = Atmp > 0 & Atmp < 1;
    Ind_Valid = find(Valid == 1);

    if (~isempty(Ind_Valid))
        % If there are valid entries, return:
        %   max(A(ind),0) if the entry is the 1st of the pair
        %   max(A(ind),1) if the entry is the 2nd of the pair
        max_Ind = max(Ind_Valid);
        x = max(Atmp(max_Ind),mod(max_Ind,2))
    else
        % If there are no valid entries, return:
        %   0 if max A < 0
        %   1 if max A > 1
        x = max(Atmp(:)) > 0
    end
end
```

Output:

```
x =

    0.3004


x =

     1


x =

    0.1000


x =

     0


x =

     1
```